# vim setting bold color hightlight

Tags: highlight

Everywhere the highlight shows bold, it has a color of light yellow on my white background. This is not bold. Its unreadable. Is there anywhere I can change this color? I can clear the highlight where it is set, but it may be easier to change its color entirely.

Comment: You might look into a different color scheme if you have a lot of problems with the one you're using.

Comment: At the moment, I am having problem with one color that is used in more than one place. That doesn't make we want to change the whole scheme, unless that is what is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are running Vim in a terminal.

Every terminal can interpret *bold* differently. For example on OS X there is a setting "Use bright colors for bold text". So you should check the preferences of your terminal.

Comment: This is a vim setting. What to do when showing bold. In this case it is showing yellow foreground. This is not the terminal setting. In vim if you issue the :highlight command, you will see term=value, cterm=value. One of these setting is bold and is configurable in vim.

Comment: You can change all these settings with highlight commands: [`:help :highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight)

Comment: @RobertJacobs yes, if it says `cterm=bold` then Vim will send the escape code for bold but your terminal emulator controls how it is displayed.

Comment: A bad setting terra term created this problem. Thanks.